# variable as a tag for xml output

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, webharvest

I am using a tool web harvest to scrape data from a website. I used xquery to output data as an xml file. I need to use a variable tag, for which I tried using the following:

```
for $i in (4 to ($count - 2)) 
return <concat("detail", $i)>{$doc//td[@class='body_copy']/b/../text()[$i]}</concat("detail", $i)>
```

This doesn't work. I also tried putting {} as in `<{concat("detail", $i)}>`
Any idea how to accomplish this? Or is it not achievable or not advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax to build element dynamically is wrong. Try this way:

```
...
element{concat("detail", $i)}{$doc//td[@class='body_copy']/b/../text()[$i]}
...
```

Result will be a `detailN` element containing the result of the expression in the seccond pair of curly braces.